# Insert div with liquid objects and get values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, liquid

I want to get the value of the inserted liquid objects. But all I'm returning is the actual text and not the values. But if I just manually insert that same div into the head and just run the logging to the console, it works fine.

I think this is a timing issue, but I can't figure it out. I am able to insert this div into the `head` of the pages on this shop [test-4658.myshopify.com](http://test-4658.myshopify.com/)
I am appending it to the head like this:

```
$('head').append('<div id="todd" class="{{customer.name}} {{shop.domain}}"></div>');
```

I confirm it by looking into the web console, but instead of getting the liquid object values, I'm just getting the text. I'm logging that to the console like this:

```
$(function(){
  var name = $("#todd").attr('class');
  console.log(name + " me");
});
```

Where did I go astray?

Comment: you can't put a div in the head so when you come to call it back, it won't exiost

Comment: why you are appending div to head?

Comment: Values from curly brackets won't resolve on their own, you have to replace them manually. Could you reproduce the issue using jsfiddle.net?

Comment: the div could be in the body as well, its really just a way to get those values from the site. @biphobe hmm, I'm not sure what you mean.. "Values from curly brackets won't resolve on their own, you have to replace them manually. "

Comment: shoot, no luck.. appended to the body, but still the same result

Comment: Ah ok sorry I didn't read your question fully, are you using the scripts in a liquid file - if not then your liquid will just be plain text

Comment: if it is in a .js.liquid file then you can try something like this: `{% raw %}'{{customer.name}}'{% endraw %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Shopify forum thread that discusses using Liquid variables in JavaScript that should help: https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/using-liquid-in-javascript-trying-to-get-collection-title-in-jquery-callback-53043

> Feel free to use customer.name in your JavaScript, simply do so in
>   your Liquid [templates](https://www.shopify.com/website/templates), not in a .js.liquid file. You can totally use
>   JavaScript in your theme's templates.

Seems like it comes down to how you implement the JS with those tags.